# Matplotlib - no picture show

Tags: python, image, function, matplotlib, rgb

I want to change the color of a specific piece of an image but running the code in Visual Studio Code doesn't display the image; however, in replit the image is displayed.

In the code, I show how to develop a function that identifies the color of the given point and then; this point is changed by the color given by the user

'#### Update [
**I explain my code
Imagine you have a chess board. The point (10,10) belongs to A8; then the program identifies the color of that point, then changes the color of the box to the given color.
Clarifications:
The given point is i and j; and the given color is RED, GREEN, BLUE all set in function argument** ]

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
```

```
def ejercicio(i, j, RED, GREEN, BLUE, imagePath="imagen1.png"):
    
    imagen = Image.open(imagePath)
    punto_color = []
    pixel = imagen.load()
    punto_color.append(pixel[i, j][0])
    punto_color.append(pixel[i, j][1])
    punto_color.append(pixel[i, j][2])
    print(punto_color)

    def color(color):
        if color[0] == punto_color[0] and color[1] == punto_color[1] and color[2] == punto_color[2]:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def paint(matrix, i, j):
        if color(matrix[i][j]):
            matrix[i][j] = [RED, GREEN, BLUE]
            paint(matrix, i, j - 1)
            paint(matrix, i, j + 1)
            paint(matrix, i + 1, j)
            paint(matrix, i - 1, j)
        else:
            return

    matrix = np.array(imagen)
    paint(matrix, i, j)
    plt.imshow(matrix)
    plt.show()

    return Image.fromarray(matrix)


print(ejercicio(400, 200, 0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: very quick (and dirty) workaround - usually works with terminal and vscode, give it a try


_plt.show(block=False)_
_input('press <ENTER> to continue')_

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the code both on Jupyter Notebook and both on VSCODE

Is this the kind of output expected (given the starting image)?

If this is the expected behavior, I suggest you to check VS CODE permissions and to save both the file and the image in the same folder.

I'll be glad to further check given some further detail on the output expected.

(lol sorry for the image, pun not intended, literally picked the first one on my hdisk)

[image]

Comment: If the image changes color, then it is the expected result. How did you do it?

Comment: Hello, sorry, to be back at you with such delay; yes, it changes just in the coordinates I give as function input values (eg. 50,50).
I did nothing , just pasted the code on my Python 3.6.5 venv. :)

Comment: Don't worry. Uncanny, it doesn't work for me